# Print array keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

Given a table called "people" where names of people are associated to their city, I need to retrieve the number of people who come from the same city.

```
PEOPLE      CITY
John        Baltimore
David       London
Paula       Baltimore
Mark        Baltimore
Alex        London
```

My code is as follows:

```
$array_cities = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM people";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $array_cities[] = $record['city'];
}
print_r(array_count_values($array_cities));
```

And what I get in my browser is:

```
Array ( [Baltimore] => 3 [London] => 2 )
```

The output is correct, but it is not graphically good. What I would want is something like:

```
Baltimore => 3 London => 2
```

Are there any other options to get it?

Comment: Loop it and correct graphically good

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: Rizier, your answer worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the output from [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). If you want something else, just loop through the array an print it:

```
foreach(array_count_values($array_cities) as $k => $v)
   echo $k . " => " . $v . " ";
```

---

**Sidenote:**

Besides `print_r()` there are also `var_dump()` and `var_export()`, which are all "debugging functions". So use them for debugging and not for printing "nice formatted output".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MySQL function COUNT(*) & the GROUP BY clause:

```
$array_cities = array();
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `persons`, `city` FROM `people` GROUP BY `city`';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array_cities[$record['city']] = $record['persons'];
    }
}
print_r($array_cities);
```